# DVWA showing blank pages when redirecting to folder vulnerabilities

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have setup DVWA using XAMPP (Apache 2.4.56 and PHP 8.2.4) on Windows 11, but when I try to access `localhost/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/`, or any other vulnerabilities, they all show a blank page.

I can access `dvwa/instructions.php` (`setup.php`,  `security.php` ...) and created dvwa database (`allow_url_fopen = On`, `allow_url_include = On` and `extension=gd`).

Apache error.log:

```
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.420390 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.471329 2023] [core:warn] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.473960 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.782512 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH00455: Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.782512 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Mar  7 2023 13:21:03
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.782512 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:14.786808 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1860:tid 400] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7260
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:15.010293 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 7260:tid 336] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:15.053751 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 7260:tid 336] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:15.092793 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7260:tid 336] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 27 15:59:17.285413 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 7260:tid 1916] [client ::1:49711] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/mutillidae/
```

I'm using Virtual Box with Windows 11 on Internal Network.

Comment: The last release of apache httpd 2.0 was in 2013. That was a different ssl/tls generation...

Comment: Sorry, it was Apache version 2.4.56. I've edited the question.

Comment: Solved, Windows Defender was turning vulnerabilities files into binary.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you, i solve it with magic trick : Read doc (not a blame)
From official documentation : https://github.com/digininja/DVWA#linux-packages

> Linux Packages
>
> If you are using a Debian based Linux distribution, you will need to
> install the following packages (or their equivalent):
>
> ```
> apache2
> libapache2-mod-php
> mariadb-server
> mariadb-client
> php php-mysqli
> php-gd
> ```
>
> I would recommend doing an update before this, just so you make sure
> you are going to get the latest version of everything.

```
apt update apt install -y apache2 mariadb-server mariadb-client php
php-mysqli php-gd libapache2-mod-php
```

> The site will work with MySQL instead of MariaDB but we strongly
> recommend MariaDB as it works out of the box whereas you have to make
> changes to get MySQL to work correctly. Database Setup
>
> To set up the database, simply click on the Setup DVWA button in the
> main menu, then click on the Create / Reset Database button. This will
> create / reset the database for you with some data in.
>
> If you receive an error while trying to create your database, make
> sure your database credentials are correct within
> ./config/config.inc.php. This differs from config.inc.php.dist, which
> is an example file.
>
> The variables are set to the following by default:

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server'] = '127.0.0.1'; 
$_DVWA[ 'db_port'] = '3306';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ] = 'dvwa'; 
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'p@ssw0rd';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
```

> Note, if you are using MariaDB rather than MySQL (MariaDB is default
> in Kali), then you can't use the database root user, you must create a
> new database user. To do this, connect to the database as the root
> user then use the following commands:

```
mysql> create database dvwa; Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user dvwa@localhost identified by 'p@ssw0rd'; Query OK,
0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> grant all on dvwa.* to dvwa@localhost; Query OK, 0 rows
affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> flush privileges; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```